# Choosing a single vector in Gelfand's formula applied to a compact operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $\rho(T)$ be the spectral radius of some compact bounded linear operator $T$ on a Banach space $(X,\|\cdot\|)$. Let $\|T\|_{op}$ be its operator norm. Then the famous Gelfand's formula says that $$\rho(T)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\|T^k\|_{op}^{1/k}=\inf_{k\in\mathbb N}\|T^k\|_{op}^{1/k}.$$
Here $$\|T^k\|_{op}=\inf\{c\geq0:\|T^kx\|\leq c\|x\|\ \forall x\in X\},$$ hence given $\epsilon>0$, we can find some $x_k\in X$ with $\|x_k\|=1$ such that $\|T^kx_k\|\geq\|T^k\|_{op}-\epsilon$.

I'm wondering whether (and if yes, under what conditions) it is possible to find an uniform element of $X$ satisfying this property. In other words, can we find some $x\in X$ with $\|x\|=1$ such that for all $k\in\mathbb N$, $\|T^kx\|\geq\|T^k\|_{op}-\epsilon$?

Heuristically, I'd like to apply the theorem of Riesz stating that we have countably many elements in $\sigma(T)$, having zero limit, with all nonzero elements being eigenvalues. Hence the spectral radius is attained at some eigenvalue; when working with a self-adjoint operator $T$, we may argue that this eigenvalue is real. Then we find an eigenvector $x$ corresponding to such a `large' eigenvalue, and hopefully this is such that $\|T^kx\|^{1/k}$ is close to $\|T^k\|_{op}$ for large $k$. If this cannot be done in general, maybe something can be proven along a subsequence of $(T^k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$? EDIT: It seems that after a few edits I have answered my own question, under the assumption of compactness and self-adjointness.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is not true.

Consider the Hilbert space $X=\mathbb{C}^3$  and  the operator $$T(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_2,rx_3,0), 0<r<1$$ Then
$$T^2(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(rx_3,0,0)$$  We have  $\|T\|=1$ and $\|T^2\|=r.$ For $\|x\|=1$ we get $$\|Tx\|^2=|x_2|^2+r^2|x_3|^2\le |x_2|^2+r^2$$ Assume additionally that  $\|Tx\|\ge 1-\varepsilon.$ Then $\|Tx\|^2\ge 1-2\varepsilon,$ and we get $$|x_2|^2\ge 1-2\varepsilon -r^2$$ Furthermore $\|T^2x\|=r|x_3|.$ Assume $\|T^2x\|\ge r-\varepsilon.$ Then $$|x_3|^2\ge \left (1-{\varepsilon\over r}\right )^2\ge 1 -{2\varepsilon\over r}$$ For $\varepsilon =r/4$ we have $$|x_2|^2\ge 1-{r\over 2}-r^2,\quad |x_3|^2\ge {1\over 2}$$ Taking $r={1\over 3}$ results in
$$|x_2|^2={13\over 18}>{1\over 2},\quad |x_3|^2\ge {1\over 2}$$ which leads to a contradiction, as $\|x\|^2=1.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, your counterexample shows that we need more assumptions on our operator $T$. It seems that compactness + self-adjointness suffices, and what I'm asking for essentially comes down to Krein-Rutman; in the finite-dimensional case, this is just Perron-Frobenius.

Comment: In case $T$ is selfadjoint and compact then the unit vector $x,$ corresponding to the  eigenvalue with greatest absolute value $\lambda,$ satisfies $\|T^nx\|=|\lambda|^n=\|T\|^n=\|T^n\|.$ There is no need for $\varepsilon.$